# Show that $A$ and $A^{-1}$ have same eigenvalues?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $A$ is a square matrix of order $2$, and determinant of $A$ is $1$, then prove that $A$ and its inverse have the same eigenvalues.

So, let $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ be the eigenvalues of $A$. Since determinant is $1$, it means $\lambda_1\,\lambda_2 = 1$. What do I do after this to reach the conclusion?

Comment: If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $Ax = \lambda x$, so...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** note that if $\lambda_1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $1/\lambda_1$ is an eigenvalue of $A^{-1}$ (why?).

Comment: why ? Because it is a standard property

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "standard property".  But if that's something you happen to know from before, then use it.

Comment: @LittleChild "Standard property" or not, it is useful to know how to prove that result

Comment: Let $\lambda_1$ be a eigenvalue of$A$, than $Ax=\lambda_1x$. This is equivalent with $x=A^{-1}\lambda_1x$ or $\lambda_1^{-1}x=A^{-1}x$. The last equality tells us that $\lambda_1^{-1}$ is an eigenvalue for $A^{-1}$.

Comment: To whoever down-voted my answer: I would appreciate an explanation as to why you decided this was necessary or how my answer could be improved.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I can understand your frustrations with down voters. The problem is there is no way to leave an anonymous comment so it is hard to see how one can improve the answers etc. This I think is a flaw in the system.

Answer (score 5):

If $A$ is 2 by 2 and has determinant $1$, then its eigenvalues are $\lambda$ and $\frac{1}{\lambda}$. If you invert $A$, the $\lambda$ eigenvalue maps to $\frac{1}{\lambda}$, and the $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ eigenvalue maps to $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\lambda}} = \lambda$. Thus, they have the same eigenvalues.

This follows from $A x = \lambda x \iff \frac{1}{\lambda} A x = x \iff \frac{1}{\lambda}x = A^{-1} x \iff A^{-1} x = \frac{1}{\lambda} x$ for invertible $A$.